# slice an image with css in different sizes

Tags: css, css-sprites

I need to **slice** this image in css to use as background
http://i28.lulzimg.com/f0f166e559.png

but I can't find a proper *solution* on how to do it, I wants to have this same background in
different sizes but have same size for title top corner.

http://screensnapr.com/v/9h30Wr.png

Please can someone guide me proper css for this image as background.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you considered Photoshop?

Comment: I need proper css code for using this image as background, and photoshop is not generating such code for this image.

Comment: I mean use Photoshop to slice the image and CSS to put the elements together as you like.

Comment: Thank you for reply but problem is I am not sure how I will accomplish it with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is almost pure CSS solution. Tested in Chrome only. Tweak image sizes and margins to suit your needs. You only need two small images cropped from your big picture:

- [grain.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlegB.png#1) for content area background
- [title.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlegB.png) for top-right title area background

**CSS (base.css)**

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#title_element {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 191px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #1f252b;
    background: url("title.png") no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

#title_bar {
    position: relative;
    background: #1f252b;
    height: 6px;
    margin-top: 21px;
    border-left: 1px solid #4d5259;
    border-right: 1px solid #4d5259;
    border-top: 1px solid #4d5259;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    background: #191e25;
    background: url("grain.png") repeat;
    border: 2px solid #191e25;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

**HTML (index.html)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="title_element">
        <h1>Your Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="title_bar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lots</p>
        <p>of</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>to</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>this layout to work ok</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what i needed, tested in all browser and worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
div{
    width:633px;
    min-height:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:60px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/U0NhH.jpg) repeat-y top left ;

}
div:after, div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/J6kEf.jpg) no-repeat ;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
}
div:after{
    top:-35px;
}
div:before{
    height:10px;
    bottom:-10px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/J6kEf.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zADDG/

**UPDATED:**

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zADDG/2/

Comment: Thank you sandeep for your efforts but still there is a problem in your code, with your code I cant use same style to make different size of boxes small/large in width and height , I wants it to be a flexible div which can auto adjust with content inside.

Comment: are you want width have to be flexible ?

Comment: in your example ur width size is 633px, lets say i wants to make a new div with 433px and see I lost top and bottom images http://jsfiddle.net/zADDG/1/      and http://screensnapr.com/v/jmy9DW.png  and your height code is working perfect... thank you again.